# Error while running sample code of V8 javascript engine

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, v8, embedded-v8

I am getting below error while trying to run code at link 1. Please help how to resolve this

> Link 1 : https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started#audience

------------------------------------Error Starts--------------------------------------

```
amit-macbook:v8 amit.sood$ g++ -Iinclude hello_world.cpp -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.release/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase.x64,snapshot},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libbase.x64.a'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicui18n.a'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicudata.a'
```

------------------------------------Error ends--------------------------------------

I installed V8 using below Link 2. I installed 64 bit version of it

> Link 2 : https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP

Answer (score 1):

I put together a guide here for building v8 on Mac OSX after I had success with it on my machine - let me know if this works for you, would love feedback: https://gist.github.com/netpoetica/28ce31478cfc43edcaa7

Additionally, specifically regarding your problem: there are a couple of possibilities here. Firstly, make sure you actually have a /out directory - which would have appeared after calling `make`. Next, when you called `make`, you may not have actually creted a folder called out/x64. Instead, you may (likely) have called `make native` or maybe `make ia32 -j 2` or something like that - the folder name x64.release should only exist if you used make like so:

`make x64
// or
make x64.release`

Answer (score 0):

You need to build v8 with static library flag set to `True`. This can be done as follows.

> Edit the default build configuration by running gn args out.gn/x64.release. Add two lines to your configuration: is_component_build = false and v8_static_library = true

After that step, the regular `ninja -C out.gn/x64.release` should give you the required libraries

Source: https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting%20Started%20with%20Embedding#run-the-example